# TextView in ListView not selectable on entire row

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, clickable

My XMLs are

activity_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dp" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/categoriesList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the customAdaptor

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/categoryIDText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible">
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/categoryName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20px" >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

So, within each row, I have two textViews. One is hidden, and other is visible.

Now, when I click on any row, the only clickable area is the one where TextView's string ends.

i.e. if my TextView categoryName has one element set as `Hello` then the listview's row looks like

Hello [BLANK SPACE HERE]

And when i touch the are where it is BLANK SPACE, it does not respond to the touch. But when I touch the area, where it is `Hello`, then it responds.

What should I do to make the entire row clickable?

Thanks

**EDIT**

```
        listView.setAdapter(new CategoryAdapter(this, categories));
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            }
```

And my custom adaptor

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_category, parent, false);
    TextView textViewID = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.categoryIDText);
    TextView textViewName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.categoryName);
    textViewID.setText(""+data.get(position).getId());
    textViewName.setText(data.get(position).getName()); 
    return rowView;
}
```

Comment: Post your clicks listener, please. Specifically where you add it to the view.

Comment: try `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` and `android:clickable="false"` to the TextView

Comment: Where have you mentioned onclicklisteners for your textview?

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal Still nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently I had to change the `android:layout_width` root element of my activity.xml file.

That did the trick for me.

Comment: Then it's about the size of the whole listview. I thought it was because of the width of the rows :(

Answer (score 1):

The root element of your listview item has `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` change it to `match_parent` (in your customAdaptor xml)

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:clickable="false"` to the TextView. This will make the touch event fall through to your underlying row.

Comment: Did you add it to both TextViews?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the visibility to "gone"?

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/categoryIDText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone">
</TextView>
```